# python slicing multi-demnsional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Could any one explain me how does the command (`<---`) below works in python numpy

```
r = np.arange(36)
r.resize(6,6)

r.reshape(36)[::7] # <---
```

Comment: This isn't slicing a multi-dimensional array; only the resize produced such an array, the reshape produced a single dimension again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to run the commands one by one and analyse their output:

- Create a list of the first `[0, 35]` numbers.

  ```
  >>> r = np.arange(36)
  >>> r
  array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
         17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
         34, 35])
  ```
- Reshape the list *in-place* to a `6 x 6` array:

  ```
  >>> r.resize(6,6)  # equivalent to r = r.reshape(6,6)
  >>> r
  array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
         [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
         [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
  ```
- Reshape the vector `r` to a 1Dimensional vector

  ```
  >>> tmp = r.reshape(36)
  ```

  `tmp` above is exactly the same as `r` in the first step
- Filter *every `7`* element

  ```
  >>> tmp[::7]
  array([ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35])
  ```

  Slicing/Indexing is represented as `i:j:k`, where `i = from`, `j = to` and `k = step`. Thus, `5:10:2` would mean *from element 5th to the 10th, give me elements every 2 steps*. If `i` is not present, it is assumed to be from the beginning of the array. If `j` is not present, it is assumed to be until the end of the array. If `k` is not present it is assumed to have an step of 1 (all the elements in the range).

With all the above, you could rewrite your example in a single line as:

```
>>> np.arange(36)[::7]
```

Or if you already have `r`, which is N-Dimensional:

```
>>> r.ravel()[::7]
```

Here `ravel` will return a 1Dimensional view of `r` (preferred to `reshape(36)`).

If you want to know more about slicing, please refer to the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

At first, you are using [NumPy ndarray.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape), which reconstructs the given array to the specified shape. In your case, you are converting it to a 1-Dimension array with 36 elements.

Secondly, with the numbers between brackets, your are [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) certain values in the array. The slicing consists in 3 values per dimension, in the form of [number1:number2:number3]. If you leave the values blank (like in your case for numbers 1 and 2), you will leave them to default i.e. number1 will be 0, number2 will be -1 (the last array index) and number3 will be 3:

- The first number indicates the array index where you will begin taking values.
- The second number indicates the array index where you will stop taking values.
- Finally, the last number indicates the number of positions that will be ignored after each index reading. In your case, you are reading every 7 indexes.

Answer (score 0):

One point to add, both `reshape()` and `resize()` methods have the SAME functionality, the ONLY difference between them is **how they affect the calling array object `r`**:

- `r.resize()` have no return. It directly change the shape of calling array object `r`.
- `r.reshape()` *returns* a new reshaped array object. And leaves the original `r` unchanged.

---

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r = np.arange(36)
>>> r.shape
(36,)
>>> # 1. --- `reshape()` returns a new object and keep the `r` ---
>>> new = r.reshape(6,6)
>>> new.shape
(6, 6)
>>> 
>>> # 2. --- resize changes `r` directly and returns `None` ---
>>> nothing = r.resize(6,6)
>>> type(nothing)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> r.shape
(6, 6)
```